# Java function to perform task every minute using computer's clock

Tags: java, time

Can someone please help me? I have this java program that needs to perform a task every minute of the computer's clock.

May I know if this is possible, and if yes what is the best way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Thread every X seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541676/java-thread-every-x-seconds)

Comment: another possible dupe [How to schedule a periodic task in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). See a [complete example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541676/java-thread-every-x-seconds).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
int delay = 60000;   // delay for 1 min.
int period = 5000;  // repeat every 5 sec.
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Task here ...
        }
    }, delay, period);
```