# How to send a message with discord.java without a command

Tags: java, discord, bots

I want to be a robot that pushes messages regularly every day, but my current robot needs to send commands. How to write a robot that can push messages automatically without sending commands?

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "discord")
public DiscordApi discordApi() {
    DiscordApi api = new DiscordApiBuilder().setToken("my token")
            .setAllNonPrivilegedIntents()
            .login()
            .join();
    api.addMessageCreateListener(event ->{
        if(event.getMessageContent().equals("Ping")){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("Pong");
        }
    });
    return api;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Thread every X seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541676/java-thread-every-x-seconds)

Comment: @Minn it doesn't have any link with this question